# How can I make a Discord bot listen to my DMs instead of simple channel messages?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm messing around creating a simple quiz bot.
So far it is working well in channels, but **I would like to modify it into a DM-only quiz bot.**

I listen to commands from Discord users like this:

```
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
```

And it works **well but ONLY IN channels, not in DMs.**

I've searched for `'directMessageCreate'` or anything else but I haven't found the solution yet.

I also tried to search for tutorials and everybody starts the bot DM with a public command in a public channel, I would like to make a DM only bot.

How could I make my public bot a DM only bot?

**E D I T:**

These are my intents, which have `DIRECT_MESSAGES` listed on. Is something still missing?

```
const client = new discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"]
});
```

Comment: `messageCreate` will work fine. Do you have `DIRECT_MESSAGES` intents enabled?

Comment: Szia Zsolt. Igen megadtam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to enable the required intents and partials to be able to listen to direct messages. As you've already added `DIRECT_MESSAGES`, you must have missed the [`CHANNEL` partial](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PartialType). It's required for DMs. Although server channels will always be available, DM channels can be uncached and that's why you'll need to add it like this:

```js
const client = new discord.Client({
    intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"],
    partials: ['CHANNEL']
});
```

If you want to make a DM only bot, you'll need to check the [`channel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type) and ignore anything that's not a DM:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type !== 'DM') return;

    // handle the command sent in a DM
});
```